# WPF application instance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

WPF application has been started with email link and I have same application installed in system so once installed application opened and login in to application and after clicked on email link, it is opening another instance. 
It may be open single instance of application.
Please advise.

Thanks,
Gaurang

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84270/WPF-Single-Instance-Application or this one: https://wpfsingleinstance.codeplex.com/ . This might help.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, but seems to be a duplicate of the marked question. If it's not a duplicate of that, please state your question more clearly. See [ask] for advice on how to present the question in a clear, answerable way. And note that while your effort in English is admirable, the lack of fluency will mean that you'll need to provide more details, and in a more precise way, to offset the grammar problems. Be _very_ specific.